# Reactjs with material UI background color all page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following:

[image]

I just wannt to change background color( only page home), but I' cant, look at the picture,
this's code:

app.js

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    h1: {
      fontSize: "3rem",
      color: "white"
    },
    h4: {
      color: "white"
    },
    textMSG:{
      fontSize: "3rem",
      fontFamily: ['Estonia', 'cursive'].join(","),
      color: "white"
    } 
  },
  palette: {
    type: "light",
    primary: {
      main: indigo[900],
      light: '#ff7961',
      dark: '#ba000d',
    },
    backgroundHome:{
      paper: "#000000",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: orange[900]
    },    
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Container>
          <Header />
        </Container>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

export default App
```

home.js

```
const Home = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery((theme) => theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
    return (
        <Paper style={{ background: 'black' }}>

        </Paper>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

header.js

```
const Header = (props) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [anchor, setAnchor] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchor);
    const theme = useTheme();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down("sm"));
    const handleMenu = (event) => {
    setAnchor(event.currentTarget);
    };
    return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <HideOnScroll {...props}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <AppBar>
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography
                variant="h5"
                component="p"
                color="white"
                className={classes.title}  
                >
                <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" style={{width:'3rem', margin: 'auto'}} />
                </Typography>
                {isMobile ? (
                <>
                    <IconButton
                        style={{ color: 'white' }}
                        className={classes.menuButton}
                        edge="start"
                        aria-label="menu"
                        onClick={handleMenu}
                    >
                    <MenuIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                    <Menu
                        id="menu-appbar"
                        anchorEl={anchor}
                        anchorOrigin={{
                            vertical: "top",
                            horizontal: "right"
                        }}
                        KeepMounted
                        transformOrigin={{
                        vertical: "top",
                        horizontal: "right"
                        }}
                        open={open}
                    >
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={() => setAnchor(null)}
                            component={Link}
                            to="/"
                            color="black"
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon >
                                <HomeIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="black"> Home</Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={() => setAnchor(null)}
                            component={Link}
                            to="/Personal"
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                            <BookmarksIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="black"> Personal </Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={() => setAnchor(null)}
                            component={Link}
                            to="/College"
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                            <SchoolIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="black"> College </Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={() => setAnchor(null)}
                            component={Link}
                            to="/Skills"
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                            <CodeOutlinedIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="black"> Skills</Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={() => setAnchor(null)}
                            component={Link}
                            to="/Briefcase"
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                            <BusinessCenterOutlinedIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="black"> Briefcase</Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem
                            onClick={() => setAnchor(null)}
                            component={Link}
                            to="/About"
                        >
                            <ListItemIcon>
                            <ContactPhoneIcon />
                            </ListItemIcon>
                            <Typography variant="h6" color="black"> Contact</Typography>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </Menu>
                </>
                ) : (
                <div style={{ marginRight: "2rem" }}>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.menuButtonDesktop}
                        variant="text"
                        component={Link}
                        to="/"
                    >
                        <HomeIcon style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Typography variant="text" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '0.2rem' }} > Home </Typography>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.menuButtonDesktop}
                        variant="text"
                        component={Link}ss
                        to="/Personal"
                        color="white"
                    >
                        <BookmarksIcon style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Typography variant="text" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '0.2rem' }} > Personal </Typography>
                    </Button>                    
                    <Button
                        className={classes.menuButtonDesktop}
                        variant="text"
                        component={Link}
                        to="/College"
                        color="white"
                    >
                        <SchoolIcon style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Typography variant="text" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '0.2rem' }} > College </Typography>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.menuButtonDesktop}
                        variant="text"
                        component={Link}
                        to="/Skills"
                        color="white"
                    >
                        <CodeOutlinedIcon style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Typography variant="text" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '0.2rem' }} > Skills </Typography>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        className={classes.menuButtonDesktop}
                        variant="text"
                        component={Link}
                        to="/Briefcase"
                        color="white"
                    >
                        <BusinessCenterOutlinedIcon style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Typography variant="text" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '0.2rem' }} > Briefcase </Typography>
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        variant="text"
                        component={Link}
                        to="/About"
                        color="white"
                    >
                        <ContactPhoneIcon style={{ color: 'white' }}/>
                        <Typography variant="text" style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: '0.2rem' }} > Contact </Typography>
                    </Button>

                </div>
                )}
            </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/Personal" component={Personal} />
            <Route exact path="/College" component={College} />
            <Route exact path="/Skills" component={Skills} />
            <Route exact path="/Briefcase" component={Briefcase} />
            <Route exact path="/About" component={About} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
        </HideOnScroll>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

so, this's the problem, I am trying to setting background color black, to page home, but the color is taking it only a par, and I just want to setting all page home.

Comment: You need to show a little more code for your question to be answered. What is the ```<Container>``` component? And where is ```<Home>``` being used? I don't see ```<Home>``` in your app.js.

Comment: container is import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The material-ui `Container` component has a `max-width` property as well as `padding` by default. To disable this and have a full width container, try the following:

```
<Container maxWidth="false" disableGutters>
    <Header />
</Container>
```

Also, you should modify `Paper` to get rid of the rounded corners by adding the `square` prop, and style to cover the entire view height:

```
<Paper style={{background: 'black', height: '100vh'}} square>

</Paper>
```

Also, you'll need to import and add `<CssBaseline>` if you haven't already, to set `margin: 0` on the `<html>` and `<body>`. This could go in your `app.js`:

```
    function App() {
      return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Container>
              <Header />
            </Container>
        </ThemeProvider>
      );
    }
```

See the docs here :
https://mui.com/api/container/
https://mui.com/api/paper/ https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/#page

Comment: it work!! but still there are a line white, look at the picture, I updated

Comment: @Jonhwick That looks like it's caused by the margin that's put in by default on the ```<html>``` and ```<body>``` in most browsers. It's something that must be dealt with somehow for every website you create. I updated my answer to include the fix for this.

Comment: CssBaseline is like classic normalize.css ?

Comment: @Jonhwick Yes it's pretty much like that. You can read more about it here: https://mui.com/components/css-baseline/ Hopefully that fixes your issue and answers your question.